# Can't get extended label class to show in windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have a class that extends the `System.Windows.Forms.Label` class. I'm looking to program minesweeper for a knowledge assignment. It basically adds some functionality to the regular label and then gets instantiated in the form1.cs part.

```
public partial class Cell : System.Windows.Forms.Label
{
    private bool hasBomb;
    private bool isRevealed;
    private int neighbourBombCount;
    static int BombAmount;

    // Properties
    public bool HasBomb
    {
        get { return hasBomb; }
        set { hasBomb = value; }
    }

    public bool IsRevealed
    {
        get { return isRevealed; }
        set { isRevealed = value; }
    }

    public int NeighbourBombCount
    {
        get { return neighbourBombCount; }
        set { neighbourBombCount = value; }
    }


    // constructors
    public Cell()
    {
        hasBomb = false;
        isRevealed = false;
        neighbourBombCount = 0;
        this.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);

    }
```

and then theres the form1.cs:

```
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // Public variable declarations
    int chance;
    Random rand1 = new Random();
    static int bombAmount;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.AutoSize = false;
        this.Width = 420;
        this.Height = 420;
        createGrid();
    }

    public void createGrid()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            {

                grid[i][j] = new Cell();
                grid[i][j].Name = "grid" + i.ToString() + j.ToString();
                grid[i][j].Location = new System.Drawing.Point(i * 49, j * 49);
                grid[i][j].Size = new System.Drawing.Size(50, 50);
                grid[i][j].TabIndex = 0;


                chance = rand1.Next(0, 6);
                if (chance % 6 == 0 && bombAmount < 10)
                {
                    grid[i][j].HasBomb = true;
                    bombAmount++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <8; j++)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(grid[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
private Cell[][] grid = new Cell[8][];
```

which has some more logic beneath which is unimportant for now. The problem is that nothing is showing up, what am I missing?

Comment: Make them visible

Comment: could you elaborate on that part?

Comment: `grid[i][j].Visible = true;`

Comment: Code works.  Why are you using a jagged array?

Comment: I did try the grid[i][j].Visible = true; part, didn't give me anything in the form to show up. Extra info: I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community edition. I'm using a jagged array because that's what seemed natural to me, I've had bits and bobs of experience in different languages but decided to focus on c# for now. Maybe that is syntax I'm used to from another language I wouldn't know myself

Comment: Your code worked "as is" for me, with the exception of me having to declare the grid since you omitted it from the post.  Controls are visible by default, so you don't have to add the `Visible = true;` line.

Comment: I might have done something horridly wrong in the declaration part of the grid. Could you show me how you've done it, maybe that will sort out my problem and can mark as closed

Comment: Post your version in the code above.

Comment: Your version should be producing an exception since you aren't initializing the second part of the array.

Comment: This is how I had my grid set up. In the `public Form1()` theres a `createGrid()` function call. I can't think clear right now and might need to have everything spelled out for me. I did have the last line added `private Cell[][] grid = new Cell[8][];`

Comment: Somewhere in your code you need `grid[i] = new Cell[8];`

Comment: you only have the type specified there, you need the variable name `grid` just before the `=`.

Comment: Also, in your current code, this: `if (chance % 6 == 0)` is equivalent to `if (chance == 0)`, since the upper bound specified in the `rand1.Next` method call is exclusive. This means it will be true 1/6th of the time, on average.

Comment: @RufusL it was intended to be true 1/6th of the time. I'm working with a 8x8 grid and aproximately 10 cells should be Bombs.

Comment: @LarsTech when I throw in grid[i] = new Cell[8]; within the first loop it still doesn't give me desired result. Could you try to mark up an answer by just basic copy paste my code and the adaptions you made to it to make it work as is?

Comment: I added `grid[i] = new Cell[8];` to the createGrid routine, the first line under the `for i` loop.  If you aren't getting an exception with what you have posted, then you aren't running this code.

Comment: Added the `grid[i] = new Cell[8] ` where you said it should go. At least I get the grid to show up now. Now on to the logic behind all this and see why that aint working. At least I got some parts working now, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't initializing the second part of your jagged array.

Try adding this:

```
public void createGrid() {
  for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    grid[i] = new Cell[8];
```